spring boot RequestParam extends LinkedHashMap argument type mismatch
This code works fine if written like this
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/system/test")
public class SystemUserController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseResult index(@RequestParam LinkedHashMap<String, Object> params) {
        return ResponseResult.success();
    }
}


I want to encapsulate LinkedHashMap, so the call will report an error argument type mismatch
public class MyLinkedHashMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object> {}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/system/test")
public class SystemUserController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseResult index(@RequestParam MyLinkedHashMap params) {
        return ResponseResult.success();
    }
}

I am using spring boot 2.7. I tried searching for related issues but could not find a solution.
I tried searching for related issues but could not find a solution.
Using MyLinkedHashMap throws the error:
Controller [com.example.test.TestController]
Method [public java.lang.String com.example.test.TestController.index(com.example.test.MyLinkedHashMap)] with argument values:
 [0] [type=java.util.LinkedHashMap] [value={}] ] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.73.jar:9.0.73]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Any key read and Fixed key reading
public class MyLinkedHashMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object> {
    public int getInt(String key, int defaultValue) {
        Object value = get(key);
        // if(valueIsNull(value)) {
        //     return defaultValue;
        // }
        return Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(value));
    }


    public int getKeyPageNo() {
        int pageNo = getInt("pageNo", 1);
        if (pageNo <= 0) {
            pageNo = 1;
        }
        return pageNo;
    }

    public int getKeyPageSize() {
        int pageSize = getInt("pageSize", 10);
        if (pageSize <= 0 || pageSize > 1000) {
            pageSize = 10;
        }
        return pageSize;
    }


    // like... any key
    public String getKey(String key) {
        return get(key).toString();
    }
}

code:
https://github.com/ClearSeve/stackoverflow-posts-78573810

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Do you want to provoke an error but don't get it? Or do you want to force only instances of MyLinkedHashMap to be used here? If the latter, how would that type information be passed and why would that be necessary? If the former, what exactly do you want to achieve by provoking the error?

I want to be able to call it normally. Now I will get an error when using MyLinkedHashMap. Later I will add a custom method to MyLinkedHashMap

When asking about errors you should provide the details, e.g. a stack trace. At the moment my guess would be that Spring doesn't know how to deserialize json into MyLinkedHashMap since it lacks mapping information (LinkedHashMap might be explicitly handled though). It also feels like a xy problem so if you could elaborate more (by [edit]ing your question) that might help.

Please write a simple test and provide it's code. If test fails provide it's log

Already added. Please take a look.

You will need a custom processor for this. The default only supports a regular LinkedHashMap or a MultiValueMap not your custom instance. As you already discovered. So if you really want this (I don't see why) you wold need to create your own MethodArgumentResolver to cover this case. But why are you using a map in the first place and not map to a regular DTO (as recommended).

Can you write a simple example?

No as there is no simple example of this. It requires some configuration as well as writing a dedicated HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. What I don't understand is your focus on using a custom map, instead of just creating a DTO to bind to. If you really want a map just use a Map interface and don't bother about the impementation.

I will pass in some unknown and variable parameter names, extends LinkedHashMap has some fixed values that I can also obtain

As stated in the Reference Guide of Spring and the javadoc of @RequestParam it supports Map and MultiValueMap. Both are interfaces and not concrete implementations.
For the regular Map it will create a LinkedHashMap and for the MultiValueMap it will use the LinkedMultiValueMap. Those are internal decisions from the Spring team.
Your initial solution with the LinkedHashMap worked by luck as that was the exact type being used internally by Spring. You should have used the Map interface instead (it is generally a good idea to program to interfaces).
It is actually not really recommended to use the Map to get all the parameters if generally is a better approach to craft a dedicated form object. A DTO onto which you will bind the request parameters (automatically done by Spring).
If you really want to use your custom map you would need to write a dedicated HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, which in this case could be tricky especially if you want to use it for all types of requests (including multi part ones). It will also involve some additional configuration to setup the MVC part of Spring.
Generally you should opt for using DTO's unless you have a very good use-case to use a map. However generally what I have seen when projects use a Map is that they start to do mapping to a DTO themselves and/or manually. Instead of letting a framework do the heavy lifting.

Can I use the internal logic of Spring to add my type?

As stated (twice already) you need your own custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver but as stated also twice you should prefer DTO's and not a map.

Can DTO have any key name?

No you will make one DTO for each usecase / endpoint. But that all is leading up to a new question, yur question is about the use of a custom map implementation which by default isn't supported. If you want more analysis write a new question explaining your usecase instead of re-using this question.

@ClearSeve Sorry I was wrong, my example not working even for me. I apologize. I think we shall stop our efforts with extending LinkedHashMap Really it does not have any practical sense

@Alex Thank you very much. I'm trying, but if it doesn't work, I'll give up

@Alex This issue has been resolved. Add a custom parameter parser and set the priority of the custom parser.(Higher than Spring parameter parser)

@ClearSeve Thank you, I will remember. Truly speaking I had never extend Java core classes, I use DTO
